# Extract from a list of directories only specific directories

Tags: linux

I've extracted in a file named List1 all the directories and subdirectories from my computer. Now I need to create a file List2 that extracts from List1 all the directories and subdirectories that contain specific names such as " old ", " backup " and so on. I hope my question is clear enough :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` on `List1`, or instead of the two-stage process use `find` to create a list of such directories only.

#### Approach 1:

```
grep "old\|backup" List1 > List2
```

or

```
grep -E "old|backup" List1 > List2
```

This will parse `List1` for all lines containing `old` or `backup` and redirect the output to `List2`.

#### Approach 2:

```
find / -type d \( -name "*old*" -o -name "*backup*" \) > List2
```

This will search the directory tree starting from `/` , find only directories (`-type d`) where the name contains `*old*` or `*backup*`, and write the output to `List2`.

Comment: Note the difference in result though. The `grep` approach would get _any pathname_ that contain the strings while `find` would only output the pathname to the directories that contain the string (not the contents of these directories).

Comment: @Kusalananda I had the impression that `File1` contained a list of directories only, so the `grep` approach also should only output directories (assuming I understood your comment correctly).

Comment: Yes, but a directory may be part of and hold another directory, e.g. `backup/01`, `backup/01/0f` etc.